# Java: PDF converter works in Mac but in Windows, produce empty PDF file

Tags: java, file, pdf, byte, agents-jade

I need a little help here with my PDF converter program.

So, I'm doing this mobile agent PDF converter using JADE framework. But, the problem that I am facing is more related to the way I convert a text file into PDF, send it across network as binary and restore PDF file back.

The program that I've written works properly on my MacBook.
But, on a Windows, it restores my PDF file as an empty PDF.

Here is my code that I use for sending the PDF file across.

```
private void sendPDF(File f, String recipient) {
    String content = "";

    if(f != null) {
        try {
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(f);
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

            int noBytesRead = 0;
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

            while((noBytesRead = fis.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                baos.write(buffer, 0, noBytesRead);
            }

            content = baos.toString();
            fis.close();
            baos.close();

            System.out.println("Successful PDF-to-byte conversion.");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Exception while converting PDF-to-byte.");
            content = "failed";
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } else {
        System.out.println("PDF-to-file conversion failed.");
        content = "failed";
    }

    ACLMessage message = new ACLMessage(ACLMessage.INFORM);
    message.addReceiver(new AID(recipient, AID.ISLOCALNAME));
    message.setContent(content);

    myAgent.send(message);
    System.out.println("PDF document has been sent to requesting client.");
}
```

And, here is the code that I use to restore the PDF back.

```
private File restorePDF(String content) {
    String dirPDF = dirBuffer + "/" + new Date().getTime() + ".pdf";
    File f = new File(dirPDF);

    try {
        if(!f.exists()) f.createNewFile();

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(content.getBytes());
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(f);

        int noBytesRead = 0;
        while((noBytesRead = bais.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                fos.write(buffer, 0, noBytesRead);
    }

        fos.flush();
        fos.close();
        bais.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        f = null;
    }

    return f;
}
```

Any help on this would be much appreciated! :)

Comment: Any log ? Exception ? Trace ?

Answer (score 1):

Question is a little bit confusing, since there is nothing specific about PDF content.

I am supposing you actually want to send bytes, actually send a string, and the string encoding is different on the client and server.

This is usually where troubles happen:

```
 content = baos.toString();
```

and:

```
 content.getBytes()
```

Comment: I think that's it. Combined with the fact that reading in a PDF and then converting it into a string seems very risky even if the encoding matches on both ends. @hsoetikno: Cannot you just write bytes? If not, maybe use BASE64 or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

A PDF file is a binary file format with lookup tables and lots of binary data blocks to making it a String will break it. If you want to know about the insides of a PDF file, I have written a whole load of blog posts about it  (http://www.jpedal.org/PDFblog/2010/09/understanding-the-pdf-file-format-series/)

Answer (score 0):

One issue is that you're using the wrong separator char. Java has a built in function that will return the correct char for the correct os. See [separator char](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/File.html#separatorChar).

Your code will look something like this

```
String dirPDF = dirBuffer + File.separatorChar + new Date().getTime() + ".pdf";
```

For reference:

> separatorChar
>
> The system-dependent default name-separator character. This field is
>   initialized to contain the first character of the value of the system
>   property file.separator. **On UNIX systems the value of this field is
>   '/'; on Microsoft Windows systems it is '\'.**